# selection of last-child in xml document

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-sql

I've started exploring c# and am looking at handling xml.

```
var doc = XDocument.parse("some.xml");

XElement root = doc.Element("book");
root.Add(new XElement("page"));
XElement lastPost = (XElement)root.Element("book").LastNode;
if (!lastPost.HasAttributes)
{
     lastPost.Add(new XAttribute("src", "kk");
}

doc.Save("some.xml");
```

now, I build xml file

```
<flare>
 <control >
 <control />
 <pages>

 </pages>
</flare>
```

I need to add to pages `<page name="aaa" type="dd" />`
So far I've got it to add `<page>` but how do I add attribute? For this I must somehow select last child of `<pages>` ...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you building some xml, or querying existing one? I don't see any `book` elements in your sample xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some xml like

```
<book>
  <pages>      
  </pages>
</book>
```

And you want to add `page` element with some attributes, then

```
var pages = xdoc.Root.Element("pages");
pages.Add(new XElement("page", 
                       new XAttribute("name", "aaa"), // adding attribute "name"
                       new XAttribute("type", "dd"))); // adding attribute "type"
xdoc.Save("some.xml"); // don't forget to save document
```

This will add following `page` element:

```
<book>
  <pages>
     <page name="aaa" type="dd" />      
  </pages>
</book>
```

Modifying attributes of last page is also simple:

```
var lastPage = pages.Elements().LastOrDefault(); // getting last page if any
if (lastPage != null)
{
    lastPage.Add(new XAttribute("foo", "bar")); // add new attribute
    lastPage.SetAttributeValue("name", "bbb"); // modify attribute
}
```